# Node application not running on remote server, runned on PC

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu

I have a program developed in javascript that runs in node, it works perfectly on my windows and ubuntu environment but for some reason, it does not work on a remote new server I installed it.

I did the same things I did with my personal environment, install node, install MongoDB, install the packages and run it. but for some reason, it shows an error it didn't show before

Error:

```
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 547ms


/home/servinfo/DynamicButtons/build/webpack:/src/routes.js:18
module.exports = app => {
^

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/servinfo/DynamicButtons/build/webpack:/src/routes.js:18:1)
```

I execute it using backpack-core, I run "npm run dev" and showed me this error(actually bigger but this is what matters)

Comment: Usually what I do in this cases:
- remove node_modules/
- remove package_lock.json
- npm install again

Comment: Also check node version, and your backpack-core version

Comment: thanks to you both , there was a node version 6 and i developed using 10.

Comment: by the way why did you comment instead of answering?

Comment: Good point left an answer, may be useful for other guys, but usually, if it's just an idea or a question I write a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually what I do in these cases:

- check node version
- check package.json to have all the dependencies including devDependencies for package managers and other building services
- remove node_modules/
- remove package_lock.json
- npm install again

That usually helps